# What is the language code for a simplified/plain language

Tags: translation, accessibility

I received a translation for a software in plain german (["einfaches deutsch"](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leichte_Sprache)). I am really happy about this because I think accessibility is really important. However, in order to integrate it, I need a code for that language.

I usually use 2-letter ISO codes for that, e.g. `en` or `de`. I already knew that you could add a territory code like `en-US` or `de-AT`. By reading [RFC5646](https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5646.txt) I found out that what I am looking for is probably a *variant subtag* like `de-simple`.

However, these variant subtags need to be registered with IANA. I browsed the [language subtag registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry/language-subtag-registry) there and did not find any variant subtag that matches what I was searching for. So it seems like there is no variant subtag for plain language.

So I see three options here:

- I missed something.
- I just go ahead and use an unofficial language code such as `de-simple`.
- I register the `simple` subtag with the IANA.

Which one is it?

Comment: I send an email containing further research to iana for discussion: http://article.gmane.org/gmane.ietf.languages/10778

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the meantime, a `-simple` variant tag has been standardized, so now it is possible to use `de-simple`. See [this blog post](http://tobib.spline.de/xi/posts/2017-06-26-simple-language/) for details.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no language tag for simple languages. [It has been discussed](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.ietf.languages/10778) but there were to many open questions. The best option for now is probably to use a private use subtag, e.g. `de-x-simple`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you simply use the language tag on its own. i.e. `lang="de"` because this is supposed to be the non-specific language tag - which correlates pretty much with "einfaches Deutsch".

If you read the definition of "Leichtes Deutsch" then you will see that it is a style of speaking/writing that is independent of dialect or variant. It is like a style of writing in the same sense that Shakespeare has a style of writing and Dr. Seuss has a style of writing.

In either case, the RFC states quite clearly that subtags must be registered before being used

```
   Variant subtags MUST be registered with IANA according to the
   rules in Section 3.5 of this document before being used to form
   language tags.  In order to distinguish variants from other types
   of subtags, registrations MUST meet the following length and
   content restrictions
```

Comment: Simply using `de` does not work because there are supposed to be two german translations: One for german and one for simple german.

Comment: That does not matter for the purposes of accessibility